# Remote Access to Multiple Pi using Mobile Hotspot

Tags: networking

I have a setup which has multiple Pi's connected to dlink router on the LAN ports. I want to remotely access the Pi over internet. I cannot provide internet to my LAN ports. Can I remote access the Pi using a mobile hotspot connected to dlink router configured as wireless repeater??if yes how can I do this

I have seen many tutorials on Port forwarding and even tried to configure it on my setup but I am not able to access the raspberry pi....please help as I am a noob in networking

Comment: Imagine that your RPi1 has a local IP address `192.168.1.2`, your RPi2 has a local IP address `192.168.1.3`, then on your home router, you must add `PAT / NAT rules` ... Add 192.168.1.2 and authorize access to all ports or just for example port 22 for ssh this is according to your needs ... do the same for RPi2 and ip addr 192.168.1.3. There are different ways to add the rules.

Comment: @Ephemeral how and where to add the rules??

Comment: On your router administration. Try this ip addr in your webbrowser : `192.168.0.1`. But, take your dlink router model and use search motor with keywords `dlink [MODEL] access to administration`

Comment: Also, your RPi(s) must have static local ip addr, you cannot use the same port for (example) ssh ... In your case you must add rules for specific port because you have multiple access behind NAT.

Comment: @Ephemeral Thanks for suggestion....what i did so far is configure router as wireless repeater and port forwarding to the RPis for example 8080 to 22 on 192.168.1.101(RPi1) ......when i check the port using portchecker.com it shows port is closed

Comment: I think you  must add rules on the repeater and also on the repeated router.

Comment: @Ephemeral My internet access point is mobile hotspot which is wirelessly connected to my router.....the router is configured as repeater......what am i missing??

Comment: Your phone cannot do PAT I think...

Comment: @Ephemeral No idea!!

Comment: You have multiple RasPis which are wired connected to a dlink router. The dlink router is wireless connected to a mobile hotspot. What is this mobile hotspot? A cell phone? You have to configure the dlink router and maybe the mobile hotspot. The RasPis just connect out of the box by wire to the dlink router. So what is the problem with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Ingo The mobile hotspot is the cell phone ......I want to have remote access to the Raspi

Comment: As already noted in my comment before: we have to assist to configure the dlink router but that is not a problem of Raspberry Pi and out of scope here. You should better ask at https://superuser.com/